# Spring Integration using DirectChannel in IntegrationFlow throws "Dispatcher has no subscribers"

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have this very basic setup of `IntegrationFlow` with Spring Integration Java DSL:

```
@IntegrationComponentScan
@EnableIntegration
@Configuration
public class DummyConfig {

    @MessagingGateway
    public interface DummyGateway {
        @Gateway(requestChannel = "dummyInChannel")
        void echo(String payload);
    }

    @Bean(name = "dummyInChannel")
    public MessageChannel dummyInChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.direct().get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow dummyFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(dummyInChannel())
            .handle(String.class, (payload, headers) -> {
                System.out.println(payload);
                return "";
            })
            .get();
    }

}
```

When I try to post a message to my gateway

```
dummyGateway.echo("test");
```

I'm getting and exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: 
Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application.dummyInChannel'.; nested exception 
is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher 
has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=test, 
headers={replyChannel=nullChannel, id=6e4302e4-95f0-bf5a-c1a3-e8cd587c23fb, timestamp=1643269549272}]
```

I thought, that doing `.handle()` in my flow is exactly subscribing to a channel. Then, why am I getting this exception? How to properly subscribe to my channel in this scenario?

Comment: How does it work if you do `IntegrationFlows.from("dummyInChannel")` instead?

Comment: @ArtemBilan I'm getting exactly the same exception with `IntegrationFlows.from("dummyInChannel")`.

Comment: Oh! Show us, please, when do you call that `dummyGateway.echo("test");`. Don't you do that too early in the application lifecycle? Are you really waiting until the application context is fully prepared?

Comment: I'm doing this call in the constructor of another `@Component` which has dependency on  my `DummyConfig.DummyGateway` so I would assume the application context is already initialized. By the way, if I change the type of channel to `MessageChannels.queue().get()` it works.

Comment: That is much too early in the context lifecycle.

Comment: @ArtemBilan - you're totally right. Doing the call in `@EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)` handler fixed the problem.

Comment: See my answer. I wonder if need to add something into docs...

Comment: My use case for Spring Integration is an offline batch application that should start processing immediately as it starts. This - combined with `@Configuration` based Java DSL - makes it especially easy to make the mistake I just did. So maybe this would be worth mentioning in introduction to Java DSL documentation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the ctor is too early. The beans are created at this point, but they have not started their heavy lifting. You cannot do low-level resources interaction (technically any actions) from the bean initialization phase. You need to wait until application context is fully started. Please, learn a lifecycle of Spring container: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-processor .

You may implement a `SmartLifecycle`, or listener for the `ContextStartedEvent`. But bean initialization phase is really too early to start emitting messages.

The `QueueChannel` works because it has its own internal buffer to keep messages until they are consumed. And they are consumed when the endpoint is started. In case of `DirectChannel` there is no buffer and consumer is called immediately, when we send a message. There is just no subscriber yet on that channel within bean initialization phase.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(DummyConfig.class);
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = application.run(args);
         ctx.getBean(DummyGateway.class).echo("MyAwesomeString");
        ctx.close();
}
```